# Diffeomorphism between a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and $\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Problem 5-1 from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds ask us to show that the submanifold $\Phi^{-1}(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$, where $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is given by
$\Phi(x,y,s,t) = (x^2 + y, x^2 + y^2 + s^2 + t^2 + y)$.

For me, it seems natural to try to show the map $F: \Phi^{-1}(0,1) \to \mathbb{S}^2$ given by $F(x,y,s,t) = (y,s,t)$ is a diffeomorphism. However the condition $x^2 + y = 0$ implies that if $(x,y,s,t) \in \Phi^{-1}(0,1)$, then $y \leq 0$ and so the map $F$ cannot be surjective.

Any idea is welcome!

Comment: I suggest you instead consider the mapping $F(x,y,s,t)=(x,s,t)$ to the hypersurface $x^4+s^2+t^2=1$ in $(x,s,t)$-space.

Comment: Thank you, @TedShifrin! I think that works!

Comment: Of course, then you must show that surface is diffeomorphic to the usual sphere. Indeed, this should work for any (smooth) convex surface.

Comment: Yeah, I've got it!

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that your suggested map $F(x,y,s,t)=(y,s,t)$ is not surjective. To get an idea how to fix that, notice that it is also not *injective*, because $F(x,y,s,t)=F(-x,y,s,t)$.

The correct diffeomorphism should be $F(x,y,s,t)=(sign(x) \cdot y,s,t)$.
It solves both your problems of surjectivity and injectivity.
It remains to check that the map is smooth for points with $x=0$.

Comment: It seems $C^1$ to me, but not smooth.